# Listing WooCommerce best selling products without a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

So, I have been trying to do exactly the same thing as the `[products limit="10" columns="4" best_selling="true" ]` shortcode does.

I need to implement it to a php page template, but I have read that do_shortcode is bad practice, and I would like to do it the right way.

This is what I have so far, but where do I go from here?

```
$args = array(
        'limit' => '10',
        'columns'      => '4',
        'orderby' => 'total_sales',
        'order' => 'DESC',
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
```

If I understand it correctly this will save the 10 best selling products, descending by the number of total sales into $products. Is this not correct?

How do I show the actual product listings from $products correctly (just like the shortcode would do)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`total_sales` can be set in the query using `meta_key`.

Once you return the results from the query, you just need to loop through them and output whatever attributes you need.

```
$args = array(
        'limit'     => '10',
        'orderby'   => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' ),
        'meta_key'  => 'total_sales',
    );

    $query    = new WC_Product_Query( $args );
    $products = $query->get_products();
    if ( $products ) {
        foreach ( $products as $product ) {
            echo $product->get_name(); // Here, we're just listing each product's name
        }
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
```

**Update**

With this update, we're now using the results from `wc_get_products()` on a  [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) adapted from `archive-product.php`. The goal here was to avoid using WP_Query/get_posts(), as they are [not recommended for product querying](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query#description).

> wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query provide a standard way of retrieving products that is safe to use and will not break due to database changes in future WooCommerce versions. Building custom WP_Queries or database queries is likely to break your code in future versions of WooCommerce as data moves towards custom tables for better performance. This is the best-practices way for plugin and theme developers to retrieve multiple products. wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query are similar to WordPress get_posts and WP_Query. Just like those, you pass in an array of arguments defining the criteria for the search.

We're now able to get the same layout/styles that normal product category/archive pages have, but with our top-sellers query. We have the product title, image, price, and add-to-cart button and all of the WooCommerce/theme styles applied without having to build everything from scratch as with the previous method (above).

Tested and working in WooCommerce 3.5.6

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
get_header( 'shop' );
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>
    <header class="woocommerce-products-header">
        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
            <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header>
<?php


if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_get_products' ) ) {
    return;
}
echo '<div class="woocommerce">'; // needed for default styles 
$top_selling_products = wc_get_products( array(
    'meta_key' => 'total_sales', // our custom query meta_key
    'return'   => 'ids', // needed to pass to $post_object
    'orderby'  => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' ), // order from highest to lowest of top sellers
) );
if ( $top_selling_products ) {
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();
    foreach ( $top_selling_products as $top_selling_product ) {
        $post_object = get_post( $top_selling_product );
        setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );
        do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
} else {
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}
echo '</div><!-- .woocommerce -->';

do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
get_footer( 'shop' );
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't the WooCommerce docs say that WP_Query shouldn't be used and wc_get_products or WC_Product_Query should be used instead? Or did I misunderstand that?

Comment: Oh lord, it's been a long day. Sorry about that. Updated!

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to get the "whole listings" like the shortcode would do? With the Product image, the product name, price, add to cart button?

I checked the docs but I couldn't find the relevant part unfortunetely

Comment: Updated with a method to include the product name, image, price and add-to-cart button.

Comment: Wow thank you! Works perfectly! Thanks for the explanation as well!

Comment: with 'meta_key', the wc_get_products() doesn't work? Any solution?